# Error is using Microsoft Query data in excel in 3rd Person's PC

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, sql-server

I have a problem when using Microsoft Query in Excel Data Link.

I have used SQL Server Connections before in Excel. When we use SQL Server, after doing the connection and retrieving the data, the datas can be viewed and refreshed by any PC as long as they are connected to the SQL Server.

Is this different in when using the Microsoft Query Data Connections. Because i did a Data connection through Microsoft Query. I worked fine in my PC. But when another user tried in his PC, there was a little problem.

When the user tried to refresh the data, the excel asked him to select the data source and showed a new window named "Select Data Source".

I would like to know if this is because the Microsoft query will only work on the creater's PC or is it that i made some mistake when creating the Microsoft Query.

To make it more clearer i have attached the image of the window below.

[Window Pop UP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK5wI.png)

Comment: I couldn't place the image here as i don't have enough reputations. but i have placed it as a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Excel 2007 or later, I would forget about Microsoft Query and use the External Data functionality (on the Data ribbon).  There's a walkthrough here:

http://excelusergroup.org/blogs/nickhodge/archive/2008/11/04/excel-2007-getting-external-data.aspx

There are many advantages to this approach, but relevant to your specific issue is that it can store the connection information inside the Excel workbook.  It is still reliant on drivers being installed, but an Office install normally gets you SQL Server drivers.

Moving forward to Excel 2010 or later, the Power Query Add-In is even better.  You can shape, transform and combine external data in all kinds of ways, with great performance and integration with Excel and Power Pivot.

Comment: I am using Excel 2007. Also i created the worksheet using the External Data Functionality that you have mentioned here.  I used the Microsoft Query function under the Other Data Sources. I have followed the steps shown here in the walkthrough. But i am still getting this error.

Comment: To add in : Mine is a Windows 7 system but my collegue is using a Apple Mac notebook. Could this error be due to the difference in OS?

Comment: dead link, ....

Comment: yeah .. dead tech also. Power Query is clearly the best tool for this challenge now, and baked into Excel 2016+.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up identical system DSN ODBC connections on both your computer and your colleague's computer?

When I've made Excel files that used Microsoft Queries, I always connected to the SQL Server database using a system DSN ODBC connection.  (I dont' use "user DSNs".)

Then, whenever I shared that file with someone else, they had to have an identical system DSN ODBC connection set up on their machine in order to use the same Microsoft Queries.  To be safe, I even named the system DSNs with the same name.

And of course they need the same "select" permissions on the back-end SQL Server as you.

(Just google "how to set up a system DSN" if not familiar.)